# NSTextField prints in the center of the page

Tags: objective-c, macos, printing

When I print with NSTextField, the content shows up in the center of the page instead of justified at the top left:

```
NSTextView *printView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 468, 648)];
[printView setString:text];
[printView autorelease];



[[NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:printView] runOperation];
```

I have also tried

```
NSPrintInfo *printInfo = [NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo];
[printInfo setVerticallyCentered:NO];
[printInfo setHorizontallyCentered:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

> **OSX Objective-C Printing Template**
>
> I am building an app for OS X and I want to add a simple print
>   function, but I found that there seems to be no easy way to do this. I
>   have some text that I want to print along with a title. Is there some
>   kind of a template that I can work off of and add my own text?

If you throw `NSPrintOperation` into the Documentation search field, you will see related sample code.

Doing that: Apple provides a number of samples which use this class. The TextEdit sample also illustrates customization of printing.

Comment: I am not looking to customize a document, only to print a title and body.